# Connecting to Bloomberg Server API

Tags: api, server, bloomberg

**Background:**
My company currently has the Bloomberg SAPI running on server X and it also has BB terminal on it. I am planning to develop an .NET application to be hosted on server X and have it accessing Bloomberg data. However I am a bit unclear on few things.

**Questions:**

- Do I use BLPAPI.dll to access Bloomberg SAPI?
- If so, do I follow the documentations on https://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/ ?
- In terms of code wise, what is the difference of connecting to Bloomberg using SAPI or Desktop API or Open API (really confused here)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. Do I use BLPAPI.dll to access Bloomberg SAPI?
A1. Yes! The same Api is used to access both DesktopApi (DAPI) And ServerAPi (SAPI), although additional steps are required when using SAPI - that is Authentication, Authorization and Permissioning. I recommend to download the latest library from the Bloomberg Portal https://service.bloomberg.com.

Q2. If so, do I follow the documentations on https://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/ ? 
A2. Yes, this is the official class documentation. The Api Developer Guides are available on the Bloomberg Portal.

Q3. In terms of code wise, what is the difference of connecting to Bloomberg using SAPI or Desktop API or Open API (really confused here)
A3. The Open API is another name for Bloomberg Api, or blpapi. SAPI is a server process, that your application connects to in order to access the data. Desktop Api is used by applications to connect to bbcomm.exe, a local process that runs on same PC that runs the terminal and listens on port 8194.

Comment: Hi Mourad, thanks for your response! Few more questions: 1. Does it mean if we choose to use SAPI, then we don't need users to be logged into BB terminal on server X, instead my .NET application will need to handle authentication in the code? 2. If using DAPI, we need users to log into terminal in order to access BB data? 3. Is there a way to programatically log into BB terminal in my application? Thanks you!

Comment: Anyway I have successfully written a demo application connecting to SAPI. Cheers

Comment: That's correct, you can use Application identity to access data from SAPI, however, before distributing the data to end users, you need to check their entitlements and that requires creating and caching identity object for the user, call userIdentity.HasEntitlements(<EID's>). User must be logged in to the terminal at the time of creating his/her identity object.

It's not possible to programmatically login to the terminal, because user must use the B-UNIT to login.